# Using webview with entered string values

Tags: android, android-webview

I just want to ask you how can i use webview with an entered strings from edittext? 
For example, i created 2 fragment one of these shows webview and another one gets 2 edittext from users. I just want to get entered edittext values from 2. fragment to  1. fragment. Because i want create a URL like this : webView.loadUrl("http://www.truebilisim.com/myiphone/index.php?id=" + ID + "&sifre=" + Password);

This is my first fragment.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Tab1">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And this is the second one.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Tab2">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Tab2">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo">

        <EditText

            android:hint="ID"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/idx"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_id"
        >

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Şifre"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_pass"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="KAYDET"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too big to answer here. And its not specific. I'm just going to mention the steps. You'll find code for specific parts if you search properly.

- Initialize your `EditText`s. You you'll send the values from the `EditText`'s when the user clicks the login button.
- Set `onClickListener` on the login button. Inside the listener, check if your `EditTexts` have value or not. If they have value, goto the other fragment.
- Send the values of `EditText` to the other fragment, you can do this in multiple ways. One is, just get an instance to the destination fragment object, and send the value.

Answer (score 0):

I get these strings like this but cant find a way to use at first fragment. Can u show me ?

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {


public Tab2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
EditText ed1,ed2;
private Button b1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);

    b1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    ed1 = view.findViewById(R.id.idx);
    ed2 = view.findViewById(R.id.password);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        String n = ed1.getText().toString();
        String p = ed2.getText().toString();

        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

}